# How to insert array in nested JSON attribute through AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a JSON object, in which attributes are a bit nested. I want to insert an array into nested JSON list, please see the code below for my JSON object.

**JSON Object:**

```
{
"companyId": 1,
"formation": "c",
"location": [{
    "landmark": "Coca Cola",
    "street1": "4104 Banner Rd",
    "type": "",
    "contact": []
}, {
    "landmark": "Pepsi",
    "street1": "4304 Commercial Rd",
    "type": "",
    "contact": []
}]
```

}

**contact** array to be inserted is:

```
{
    "medium": "Office Phone",
    "serviceLocator": "800-285-3000",
    "prefered": "true",
    "locationRef": "Coca Cola"
}
```

All I want to do is something like this:

> insert CONTACT in LOCATION where LOCATION.landmark is equal to "Coca Cola"

Please guide me how do I do this, in my AngularJS controller, I'm thinking to try something like this, but doesn't work;
**AngularJS Controller:**

```
$scope.company.location.contact.landmark["coca cola"].push({

    "medium": "Office Phone",
    "serviceLocator": "800-285-3000",
    "prefered": "true",
    "locationRef": "Coca Cola"

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using `foreach`:

```
$scope.company.location.forEach(loc => {
    if(loc.landmark === 'coca cola') {
        loc.contact.push({
            "medium": "Office Phone",
            "serviceLocator": "800-285-3000",
            "prefered": "true",
            "locationRef": "Coca Cola"
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Traverse the location array and find the index where the value of landmark is equal to "Coca Cola". Insert the contact at that index

```
for(var i=0; i<$scope.company.location.length; i++)
{
   if($scope.company.location[i].landmark=="Coca cola")
   {
      $scope.company.location[i].push(contact);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to mention the index of the array

```
myArray.location[0].contact.push(contact);
```

EDIT:

You can use **`array.find()`** and then push to the specific array!

**DEMO**

```js
var myArray = {
"companyId": 1,
"formation": "c",
"location": [{
    "landmark": "Coca Cola",
    "street1": "4104 Banner Rd",
    "type": "",
    "contact": []
}, {
    "landmark": "Pepsi",
    "street1": "4304 Commercial Rd",
    "type": "",
    "contact": []
}]};

var contact = {
    "medium": "Office Phone",
    "serviceLocator": "800-285-3000",
    "prefered": "true",
    "locationRef": "Coca Cola"
};
var result = myArray.location.find(t=>t.landmark ==='Coca Cola');

result.contact.push(contact);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I don't want to mention the index because I don't know on which index there's "Coca Cola", but I want to find the landmark somehow and insert contact in that location

Comment: `find` is only going to return the first match.

Comment: @ChrisRiebschlager OP have not mentioned that requirement, he can use filter()